# How to install security cameras on ceilings?

Tags: ceiling, screws, mounting

I would like to know how to install or mount a camera on the bottom face of this **hollow** black box above the shop door. The word "Alabsh" is written on the black box as shown in image.

[image]

[image]

The bottom face of the box is above me so I would consider this as my ceiling. The ceiling is usually made of wood or metal. I know I should use a driller but what if the hole is larger than the screw/bolt?
Another question is, I can't reach the other inner side of the ceiling to use a nut. What is the alternative of using a nut?

Should I use the thing in the following image instead of the nut? But I feel like when press by the screw/bolt upward, this plastic thing will go inside the black box because it is hallow and I won't be able to get it back again. What's the best method to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hole in your "ceiling" is bigger than the anchors you might have wanted to use, your best alternative is to use toggle bolts similar to the one pictured below.

[image]

Comment: So this can fix the issue in case I made a bigger hole. What If I haven't drilled yet? Can I try to drill a whole with almost the same diameter as the screw (or a little bit smaller whole), then try to force the screw using a manual screwdriver? That's very basic but I don't know it sorry :)

Comment: @user2824371 Yes you can do that.  Hole should be smaller than screw so threads can grab the wood.  You can use a small nail and pound it in 1/4"  and use that as the hole and screw into it.